# Debugging a Windows Universal App without deploying

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I'm creating a Windows Universal App but when I run it and try to debug it, none of my changes seem to take unless I deploy first, then run/debug. It's somewhat tedious to have to do this, am I missing a setup in my environment?

-shnar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you do not have both Build and Deploy checked for each of your build targets.  Build, Configuration Manager menu.  Check all Configuration and Platform combinations...

[image: Build and Deply]